# Meaning of the verb ((be put on))

Tags: word-meaning

Please tell me the meaning of the first verb in this sentence, i.e. ((be put on)):

> We should all be put on retirement and get a new fresh group to learn the new way to teach the kinds of students that we get today.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it means that the teachers should retire.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *passive voice* expression with the verb phrase "put on retirement".

A corresponding active voice statement could start with "Someone should put us all on retirement..."

In fact the remainder of the sentence is in the *active voice*, so the original sentence doesn't make sense as a whole. And it should likely be "kind of students" rather than "kinds of students". Better statements would be

> Someone should put us all on retirement and get a new fresh group to learn the new way to teach the kind of students that we get today. (*"put" and "get" refer to the same person*)
>
> We should all be put on retirement and replaced be a new fresh group that could learn the new way to teach the kind of students that we get today. (*"be put" and "(be) replaced" both refer to "We"*)

Comment: Disagree that "kinds of students" is wrong. It just means there is more than one kind of student being referred to.